# Insert image in treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I looked up this problem and found a couple of threads, but I've used the same formula to no avail for my problem. I have three columns and I want to insert an image to the first column. What I want to do is more complicated than this, but I figure that I should make it as simple as possible to show the problem I'm encountering.
Here's my code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview( root , column=("c1","c2","c3") , show='headings'  , height = 10 , )
tree.pack(  side = LEFT, fill = BOTH )
scrollbar_tree_select_movie = Scrollbar( root )
scrollbar_tree_select_movie.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = BOTH )
tree.config(yscrollcommand = scrollbar_tree_select_movie.set)
scrollbar_tree_select_movie.config(command = tree.yview)
tree.heading("#1", text="Icon" )
tree.column("#1", anchor= CENTER , width = 50 )
tree.heading("#2", text="Name" )
tree.column("#2", anchor= CENTER , width = 300 )
tree.heading("#3", text="Year" )
tree.column("#3", anchor= CENTER , width = 50 )
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage( Image.open("the-matrix-movie-poster-xs.png")  )
tree.insert('',END,values=('','The Matrix','1999'), image=img  )
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue I had was the `show = 'headings'` option. After removing it, the image displayed.